# How can I get multiple values in a RESTful endpoint from a field who points to other resource?

Tags: 8

I have a Drupal 7.x site with RESTful installed (version 2.5) and I want have one endpoint which shows a node view, and add a field which show a index of nodes ,extracted from another endpoint, which have a entity reference field pointing to the first node.

I tried adding 'resource' key in *publicFields* method but I can only get the first result.

I saw restful obtain a resource view using ResourceFieldEntity class, calling allways *view* method inside of *singleValue* method, which only can return first value. It guess it's made in this way because singleValue don't need return more than one value, but in my case its needed, because i need the resource retrieve the complete result.

Here is where method is called, in line 336 of *ResourceFieldEntity* class.

```
   try {
     // Get the contents to embed in place of the reference ID.
     /* @var ResourceFieldCollection $embedded_entity */
     $embedded_entity = $embedded_resource
       ->getDataProvider()
       ->view($embedded_identifier);
   }
```

I solved this creating a custom resource getter class (extending *ResourceFieldEntity*), and overwrite singleValue method, and called index method instead of view method.

```
   try {
     // Get the contents to embed in place of the reference ID.
     /* @var ResourceFieldCollection $embedded_entity */
     $embedded_entity = $embedded_resource
       ->getDataProvider()
       ->index($embedded_identifier);
   }
```

Are there any other proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this module in a while, so I'm not sure if there's a major difference in the approach between 1.x and 2.x.

I would just implement a custom function for getting the single resource, so that you have full control over what is ret

```
/*
* Overrides \RestfulEntityBase::controllersInfo().
* Allows us to specify custom functions for different HTTP actions.
*/
public static function controllersInfo() {
  return array(      
   '^.*$' => array(
     \RestfulInterface::GET => 'customGetSingleExample',
   ),
  );
}

/**
* Return custom data for getting single resource result 
*/
public function customGetSingleExample() {

  //grab request values
  $request = $this->getRequest();
  static::cleanRequest($request);

  //do stuff with request (EntityFieldQuery etc)

  .....

  return $result;
}
```

This is within a **custom resource class**, which **extends RestfulEntityBaseNode**

```
class RestfulCustomResource extends RestfulEntityBaseNode {
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a custom callback to call another endpoint and it worked :) 
(i would give you the points except i don't have enough karma).

Comment: no problemo, welcome to the Drupal Stack Exchange :) glad I could help